# function declaration without definition

Tags: c++, function, c++11, declaration, definition

The following code will compile and is deterministic according to cppquiz.org (Question #30)

```
#include <iostream>
struct X {
  X() { std::cout << "X"; }
};

int main() { X x(); }
```

The output of the program is nothing, as

```
X x();
```

is a function declaration.

But still I wonder why this compiles though this declaration is never defined anywhere?

Comment: It would compile even if you did call `x`. It wouldn't link, though.

Comment: ... because it is not **used** anywhere either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `x()` is never called, there's nothing to link so no error from linker that it's not defined.  It's only declared as a function taking no arguments and returning an `X`: `X x();`.

Answer (score 3):

`X x();` itself a declaration (prototype), not a function call. If a function call is made prior to seeing its declaration then it would not compile.